# Java regex from string

Tags: java, regex

```
<InstanceIdentifier>118e3040-51d2-11e3-8f96-1110200c9a66</InstanceIdentifier>
```

This is my string, and i want the 118e3040-51d2-11e3-8f96-1110200c9a66 part.

tried this

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\b<InstanceIdentifier>\\b)(.*?)(\\b<\/InstanceIdentifier>\\b)");
```

but of course it's not working. Suggestions?

Comment: Regex can be simplified to "<InstanceIdentifier>(.*?)</InstanceIdentifier>"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the first and last `\\b` then remove the backslash which exists before `/`

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(<InstanceIdentifier>\\b)(.*?)(\\b</InstanceIdentifier>)");
```

**or**

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<InstanceIdentifier>\\b(.*?)\\b</InstanceIdentifier>");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
if(m.find())
{
System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Note that `\\b` matches between a word character and a non-word character, so the above regex must except a word character next to the starting `INstanceIdentifier` tag and before the closing `INstanceIdentifier` tag.

Your regex fails because there isn't a word character character which actually exists between the start of the line and the opening `<` bracket , likewise there isn't a word character which exists next to `>` and end of the line boundary. In this case, adding `\\B` instead of `\\b` at the start and end should work.